# VStack padding is not being apploed when VStack is wrapped in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I wrap a VStack inside a ScrollView, it seemingly removes the horizontal padding applied to the VStack causing the contents to go to the display edge as opposed to leaving space between the contents of the VStack and the edge of the display when horizontal padding is applied. I'm unsure why, or how to resolve this, but I've left reference images and my code below.

Intended Look:[image: Image with Padding applied to VStack while VStack is not wrapped in ScrollView (ScrollView is commented out)]

This is what I get when wrapping the VStack in a ScrollView:
[image: Image of result what VStack is wrapped in ScrollView. Horizontal padding is removed from VStack and buttons and text fields are touching the edge of the display.]

This is the code for what I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignInView: View {
//    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.cyan)
                    .offset(y: -100)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250)
                
                Text("Sign In to \\*\\*Name\\*\\*")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.top)
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("Sign In pressed, do something")
                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Sign In w social option")
                    }) {
                        Text("Placeholder for Social")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Sign In w social option 2")
                    }) {
                        Text("Placeholder for Social")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.black)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding the padding to the scroll view instead?

Comment: @Sweeper I attempted to remove padding from the VStack and apply it to the ScrollView, but that didn't do anything. I also just applied padding to the ScrollView, but that pushed content down, but doesn't create a space between the edge of the screen and the VStack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove width from Rectangle(). Since the width is defined as the screen width, adding padding is making the total width bigger than the width of the screen. The width isn't necessary here since views that conform to shapes such as Rectangle, circle, etc. expand to as much space as available.

For the horizontal padding, you can add the views that need padding in a stack or group and then add the padding modifier to it.

Try the following code

```
struct SignInView: View {
  //    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
  @State private var username: String = ""
  @State private var password: String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(.cyan)
          .offset(y: -100)
          .frame(height: 250)
        VStack {
          Text("Sign In to \\*\\*Name\\*\\*")
            .bold()
            .font(.system(size: 25))
          
          TextField("Username", text: $username)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding(.top)
          
          SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding(.bottom)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          
          Button(action: {
            print("Sign In pressed, do something")
          }) {
            Text("Sign In")
              .bold()
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .padding()
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
              .background(Color.blue)
              .cornerRadius(10)
          }
          
          HStack {
            Button(action: {
              print("Sign In w social option")
            }) {
              Text("Placeholder for Social")
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)
            }
            Button(action: {
              print("Sign In w social option 2")
            }) {
              Text("Placeholder for Social")
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.black)
            }
          }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
        Spacer()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that would be the explanation that I needed. It was because of the padding applied to the entire VStack that would cause the width of the rectangle to be "cut off", hence why moving the Rectangle outside of the VStack fixed the issue. Is there a reason for wrapping the Rectangle (and everthing else in the VStack) inside another VStack as opposed to just moving it outside the VStack?

Comment: Actually, the first VStack used(right after ScrollView) was unnecessary since ScrollView by default aligns vertically. Other than that, wrapping everything in VStack/Group makes it easier to add more views that may not need padding within the first VStack/Scroll View.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, partially. If someone could provide more details on why or explain the reasoning, it'd be great, but it had to do with the .frame modifier for the Rectangle. It seems like using `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` on the Rectangle within the VStack caused some issue. Moving the Rectangle outside of the VStack, but inside the ScrollView fixes it.